# Trying to hide a popup using css

Tags: html, css, popup

I kept looking to find the answer....but so far I got nothing. Is there any way for me to hide my popup (example after a delay of 4secs) only using css.

```
/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
            .popup .show {
              visibility: visible;
              -webkit-animation: fadeIn 3s;
              animation: fadeIn 3s;
            }
```

Up there I was able to show, using css. But I tried some actions like : .popup .hide and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, check out my code. I added a background and some styles for popup so there's something to display.

For animation, the 1st seconds is the duration of the animation, while the 2nd seconds is the delay which is 4s. "forwards" will allow the element to retain or not reset.

```css
.popup {
 background: black;
 width: 100px;
 height: auto;
 padding: 100px;
 animation: fadeIn 3s, fadeOut 3s 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from{opacity: 0%;}
  to{opacity:100%;}
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  from{opacity: 100%;}
  to{opacity: 0%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">

</div>
```

Comment: Notice that the popup remains on the page but it is only transparent. If you try to show something behind the popup, user is not able to click anything behind the popup (all clicks are “received” by the popup).